# Qt Framework Saving inputs To Text File

Tags: c++, qt

I was trying to make a little program with Qt Framework C++ .
I made a simple Gui which contains 5 text inputs .
How can I save these inputs into a *.txt file with this schema :

```
Name : <firstInput>
Lastname : <secondInput>
Age : <ThirdInput>
Nationality : <forthInput>
Address : <fifthInput>
```

I still didn't do anything in my main.cpp

```
#include "monformulaire.h"

#include <QApplication>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 QApplication a(argc, argv);
 MonFormulaire w;
 w.show();
 return a.exec();
 }
```

Comment: QFile and QTextStream didn't help?

Comment: If you're just learning how to code, then trying to write GUIs in Qt is far, far too complicated a way to start.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili : can you give me an exemple of how to use them ? still new to this framework and I need this asap ...

Comment: @JosephLarson : it's just i need this work to be done .. I didn't spent too much time for this framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```cpp
QFile data("output.txt");
if (data.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate)) {
    QTextStream out(&data);
    out << ui->lineEdit->text();
}
```

This tries to save contents of one of the `LineEdit`s into a file named "output.txt". You would put this code into some on-button-clicked slot.

See:

- [QFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html)
- [QTextStream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html)
- [QLineEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop)